# how can get count field in crirteria?

Tags: php, yii, count, criteria

I'm trying to build a query that has a group by user_id, select user_id,count(id) , condition, join.
i can get a true result by findall command but only i can not show count(id)
i  left my code here

in controller

```
       $criteria=new CDbcriteria();
        $criteria->condition = 'serviceId=:serviceId';
        $criteria->params = array(':serviceId'=>1);
        $criteria->group = 't.user_Id';
        $criteria->select = array('t.user_Id,count(psh_profile_information_services.id) AS count');
        $criteria->join = 'left join psh_profile_information_services on t.id=psh_profile_information_services.profileInformationId';
        $moli=  ProfileInformation::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $this->render('conectionpoint', array('moli'=>$moli ));
```

in view

```
foreach ($moli as $mol)
        {
            echo "user_Id:  ".$mol->user_id." --- count:".???????? ;

        }
```

print $mol

```
ProfileInformation Object ( [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [user_Id] => 1 [createDate] => 1393/03/23 - 15:49:26 [modifiedDate] => 1393/03/23 - 15:49:26 ) [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t [_errors:CModel:private] => Array ( ) [_validators:CModel:private] => [_scenario:CModel:private] => update [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => )
```

Comment: Change the `[...] AS count` to some different name. According to this - `count(psh_profile_information_services.id) AS count`, you are suppose to have a public variable as `public $count;` in the `ProfileInformation` model class file. If you change it to say `total_info` then you can display it as `$mol->total_info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In ProfileInformation class file -**

```
class ProfileInformation extends ActiveRecord
{
    $public $total_info;
    [....] //Rest of the code.
```

**In Controller Action,** 
change -

`$criteria->select = array('t.user_Id,count(psh_profile_information_services.id) AS count');`

to

`$criteria->select = array('t.user_Id,count(psh_profile_information_services.id) AS total_info');`

**In view file -**

```
foreach ($moli as $mol)
{
    echo "user_Id:  ".$mol->user_id." --- count:".$mol->total_info;
}
```

This should work fine.

If not, then just do simple debug -

```
echo "<pre>";

foreach($moli as $mol) {
    echo 'Total Info: ' . $mol->total_info . "<br />";
    foreach($mol as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' ' . $value . "<br />";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}

exit();
```

and check the values.

Comment: i change name of count to total_infor in view and controler but i have not any result :(

Comment: i print $mol i left in my question

Comment: i print $mol and left in my qustion

Comment: Please check the debug code added in the above answer.

Comment: Did you add the variable in the `ProfileInformation` model file too?

Comment: Its mentioned in the beginning of my answer. `class ProfileInformation extends ActiveRecord { $public $total_info; .....`